# Switch 3550 password default password

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst

What is the Cisco 3550 default password? 
I lose the password due some power outage while I was programming.
I did reboot, and try the recovery password but doesnt work.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default password. Somebody didn't save the configuration after the last password change. You do a password recovery: [Password Recovery Procedures](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-121-mainline/6130-index.html)

Specifically, for the Catalyst 3550: [Cisco Catalyst Fixed Configuration Layer 2 and Layer 3 Switches](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-2950-series-switches/12040-pswdrec-2900xl.html)

Answer (score 0):

People sometimes set these up wroth password of cisco or Cisco but there is no out of box default...

1st option start guessing

2nd option... If you have a copy of the config and the password is encrypted with type 5 or 7 enter at [this website](https://www.ifm.net.nz/cookbooks/cisco-ios-enable-secret-password-cracker.html) to get the password.

3rd option is follow the password recovery procedure given by Cisco. Follow it stop by step. I'll put it below.

4th option. If you don't care what's on the switch this may be the way to go from the start. I'll add steps below the recovery

> Password recovery [my Refrences](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11756896/cisco-switch-29603560-password-recovery-and-factory-default-mode-button)

After connecting your console cable (9600,8,none, 1) with putty or hyper terminal and test it's "talking" unplug it.

Hold down the mode button and plug switch power in. Release the Mode button after approximately 15 seconds when the SYST LED turns solid green. When you release the Mode button, the SYST LED blinks green.

At the prompt Issue the following commands. Each one followed by enter key.

```
flash_init

load_helper

dir flash: 

rename flash:config.text flash:config.old

boot
```

(System will reboot and you have a blank config)

```
Enter n for initial setup 

enable

 rename flash:config.old flash:config.text

copy flash:config.text system:running config

config terminal

enable password Cisco (use your password)

enable secret Cisco1  (use your secret)

line vty 0 15

    password Cisco2  (use your telnet password)

    login

line con 0

    password Cisco3  (use your console password)

exit

exit 

Write mem
```

Done with recovery.

If you want to factory reset there are two things that need deleted. Startup config and the vlan database.

Issue these commands and answer no to saving anything.

```
delete flash:vlan.dat

Write erase

Reload

No to any save questions
```

Switch will be ready at reboot.